# If $A$ is an idempotent matrix i.e, $A^2=A$, and given that $|A| \ne 0$, prove that $A=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Tags: matrices, determinant

> If $A$ is an idempotent matrix i.e, $A^2=A$, and given that $|A| \ne 0$, prove that $A=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Now, clearly if $|A| \ne 0$, $A^{-1}$ exists and multiplying with $A^{-1}$ in the equation $A^2=A$ yields the result. But I wanted to proceed differently.

If we take the determinant on both sides of $A^2=A$, we get either $|A|=0$ or $|A|=1$ and if we rewrite the equation as $A^2-A=A(A-I)=O$ and then taking the determinant on both sides yields $|A|=0$ and $|A-I|=0$ but since $|A| \ne 0$, we get from above two conditions i.e $|A|=1$ and $|A-I|=0$.

So my question is, do these two conditions together imply that $A=I$? Or are they still insufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are insufficient. Just take the diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $1,2,1/2$. Its determinant is one and $1$ is an eigenvalue, so $|A-I|=0$. But $A\neq I$.